# jQuery not work on Facebook fan page application

Tags: jquery

I am try to use **jquery.min.js** for a image slider on facebook fan page but it does not work.

this is the code structure:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPosition = 0;
  var slideWidth = 520;
  var slides = $('.slide');
  var numberOfSlides = slides.length;

  // Remove scrollbar in JS
  $('#slidesContainer').css('overflow', 'hidden');

  // Wrap all .slides with #slideInner div
  slides
    .wrapAll('<div id="slideInner"></div>')
    // Float left to display horizontally, readjust .slides width
    .css({
      'float' : 'left',
      'width' : slideWidth
    });

  // Set #slideInner width equal to total width of all slides
  $('#slideInner').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);

  // Insert controls in the DOM
  $('#slideshow')
    .prepend('<span class="control" id="leftControl"></span>')
    .append('<span class="control" id="rightControl"></span>');

  // Hide left arrow control on first load
  manageControls(currentPosition);

  // Create event listeners for .controls clicks
  $('.control')
    .bind('click', function(){
    // Determine new position
    currentPosition = ($(this).attr('id')=='rightControl') ? currentPosition+1 : currentPosition-1;

    // Hide / show controls
    manageControls(currentPosition);
    // Move slideInner using margin-left
    $('#slideInner').animate({
      'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)
    });
  });

  // manageControls: Hides and Shows controls depending on currentPosition
  function manageControls(position){
    // Hide left arrow if position is first slide
    if(position==0){ $('#leftControl').hide() } else{ $('#leftControl').show() }
    // Hide right arrow if position is last slide
    if(position==numberOfSlides-1){ $('#rightControl').hide() } else{ $('#rightControl').show() }
  } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: you need to tell us more if you want help. What do you want to do ? What did you try ? What is your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to relinquish jQuery's control of the `$` variable.

Have a look here [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("div").hide();
});

// Use Prototype via $(...), etc.
$('someid').hide();
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: after `noConflict()`, use `jQuery` instead of `$`

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses prototype. So, you need to use named version of jQuery