# jQuerys draggable does not work included on facebook page (basic understanding)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, jquery-ui

when trying to analyze DOM-sturcture of a facebook page I tried to implement some Javascript-Code using Greasemonkey. I included (by copy/paste) the jQuery core *and* the UI. I added via Greasemonkey the code to three sites, a rather empty one on a file located on my PC and then "instagaram"-page (just for testing) and facebook. I marked the inserted div with a thick red broder, I can see it on all three pages.

```
$('<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content" style="position:absolute;border:50px solid red;top:0;left:10px;z-index:300;">text1</div>').appendTo('body');
$( "#draggable2" ).click(function() {alert("pallo");});
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
});
alert("see if jquery is still there: " + $);
```

On both, the testpage on my PC and the instagram-page the div is draggable. On facebook I get the "alert" induced with jQuerys .click-Funktion ("pallo" in this case). But FF error console says on the Facebook-Page:

```
TypeError: $(...).draggable is not a function
```

How can Facebook possibly turn the draggable-Function off? Considering [this article here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503479/jquery-not-work-on-facebook-fan-page-application) I tried:

```
    jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#draggable2" ).draggable();
});
```

FF still says (on the facebook-page) that jQuery.draggable() is not a function.

Any ideas how Facebook "kills" the jQuery-draggable functionality? Or am I thinking or testing something wrong? This is a question more about "understanding" the techniques behind the curtains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For troubleshooting and how to do troubleshooting here:**

Looking at the DOM of facebook, there is already a variable declared as `$` in my non-hacked-up environment, and likely this is what `$` still represents in yours. Monitoring the variable and figuring out whether `$` is being overwritten, changed, modified, etc is probably going to be a road of twists and turns and regret.

For now, probably it's enough to just know that `$` exists in Facebook already and then work on a gameplan for doing what you want to do with that knowledge. You can open your browser console in FireFox by hitting `Ctrl+shift+k` and simply input `$` to have it log back in the console what `$` is.

**For solving the problem:**

The problem here most likely is related to scope within Greasemonkey. Your goal should probably be to introduce jQuery within the scope of your GM script and not within the scope of the window, so hopefully this is how you're adding the jquery files:

```
// @require     https://etc.etc.etc/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://etc.etc.etc/jquery-ui.min.js

...

this.$ = this.jQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);

//remainder of code to insert things
```

Something like this will ensure that within the scope of your Greasemonkey script, `$` refers to jQuery and jQuery-ui, and Facebook can continue to play with whatever its `$` is. :)